# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint in Entity Framework code first link table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a User table and a Roles table. There is a automatically generated UsersRoles link table which contains the Id from the User and Roles tables. This is generated using the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
                .WithMany(r => r.Users)
                .Map(c => { 
                    c.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                    c.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                    c.ToTable("UsersRoles");
                });
```

When I am trying to add an unrelated Entity and call `Context.SaveChanges()` I receive the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_UsersRoles'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.UsersRoles'. The duplicate key value is
>   (2beaf837-9034-4376-9510-b1609c54efbe,
>   dcd16d00-d46e-4d48-8328-3e7b35b11ccf). The statement has been
>   terminated.

I have checked the `Conext.ChangeTracker.Entries()` for the items mentioned in the error and the Entity State is marked as Unchanged.

The only Entity that is marked as Added is the new record I am trying to add, everything else is marked as Unchanged.

Code for adding Entity:

```
 RoleGroup group = Context.RoleGroups.Create();
 group.Title = roleGroupName;
 Context.Set<RoleGroup>().Add(group);
 Context.SaveChanges();
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You should post the code that adds the entity to the context

Comment: Can you show *exactly* what you've checked? I suspect you've only verified that the `Role` and `User` entities are unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I have updated my question to add some more information. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Did you mean `Context.Set<RoleGroup>().Add(group);`?

Comment: First there is the UsersRoles table but then the snippet refers to  RoleGroup. I definitely miss something here.

Comment: @hvd yeah that's what I mean. Will update now, thanks.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla the UsersRoles table is a link table automatically generated. The RoleGroup is unrelated, this is where I get the error trying to add a RoleGroup.

Comment: I still don' get it. How can adding a RoleGroup cause the violation of the primary key in an unrelated UserRoles table?

Comment: That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Most probably this is NOT the shown snippet that causes the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the `User` with `UserId = 2beaf837-9034-4376-9510-b1609c54efbe` and the `Role` with `RoleId = dcd16d00-d46e-4d48-8328-3e7b35b11ccf` are in state `Unchanged` does not mean that nothing gets written to the database.

Especially for many-to-many relationships (generally for independent associations) EF maintains a state for the **relationship** itself which is different from the **entity** state. If an entry gets inserted into the link table it means that the relationship entry for the two entities in question is in state `Added` although the entity state for those entities is `Unchanged`. You cannot see the relationship entry when enumerating the `DbContext`s `ChangeTracker`. It will only return entity states. You have to go down to the underlying `ObjectContext` to query for the relationship state.

Example:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var user = ctx.Users.Find(1);
    var role = ctx.Roles.Find(5);

    user.Roles = new List<Role>();
    user.Roles.Add(role);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here `user` and `role` will be both in state `Unchanged`, but still a record is inserted into the link table. And this code will throw your exception if user 1 and role 5 are already linked in the database.

Adding the `group` has nothing to do with the problem. Only the call to `SaveChanges` is causing the exception because you most likely have created a relationship between the two entities somewhere before the code snippet in your question.

Answer (score 7):

To add to Slauma's answer, it looks like if you set the ICollection property on one of these auto many-to-many things, EF gets confused and doesn't realize that you are clearing the collections elements by doing this.

So instead of doing this:

```
user.Roles = new List<Role>();
user.Roles.Add(role);
```

You have to do this:

```
user.Roles.Clear();
user.Roles.Add(role);
```

This worked for me.

You shouldn't have to do this though. This should be a bug in EF.

Comment: Just had the same issue here. Definitely should be considered a bug.

Comment: Same issue here.  In my case, I have a navigation property on a child object in a table-per-heirarchy configuration.  To get it work right, I have to manually load the children of the entity through the DbContext.Entry(entity).Collection(x => x.Children).Load().   Just loading them through a query is not enough. Then to update the list, I have to clear and add the new entries.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert the same combination of user / role into the UserRoles table:

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_UsersRoles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UsersRoles'. The duplicate key value is (2beaf837-9034-4376-9510-b1609c54efbe, dcd16d00-d46e-4d48-8328-3e7b35b11ccf). The statement has been terminated.`

Check to see which user has the ID of 2beaf837-9034-4376-9510-b1609c54efbe, and which role has the ID of dcd16d00-d46e-4d48-8328-3e7b35b11ccf.
If you are sure you've only entered that user once, is the method that inserts the data being called more than once without you realising?

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that someone will find it helpful I discovered that there's a big difference between altering an existing list in EF compared to creating a new list.

In this case I was making an update and thought it easiest to just build a new list of the items I wanted. But if some of the items were already added to the list I would get a primary key violation while saving.

I ended up keeping the same list and just making modifications to it. Clearing it and readding was ok, creating a new list was not.