# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint when inserting record in table with relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using the Entity Framework Code First with Migrations, and I created these two entities

UserAccount:

```
public class UserAccountModel
{
    [Key()]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Document { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccountAddressModel>? Address { get; set; }
}
```

And UserAccountAddress

```
public class UserAccountAddressModel
{
    [Key()]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserAccount")]
    public Guid? UserAccountld { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public int PostalCode { get; set; }
    public bool Principal { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAccountModel UserAccount { get; set; }
}
```

I already created a record in the UserAccount table in the SQL Server Database, but when I try to create the UserAccountModel with the code below, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner
> exception for details.  ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_UserAccount'.
> Cannot insert duplicate key into 'dbo.UserAccount' object. The
> duplicate key value is (a0818a30-30a1-421c-be24-08da87dafe9b).

**Inserting directly using Management Studio works normally, however using this code I get the error message above.**

The code I'm using to try to create the UserAccountAddressModel is this:

```
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(CreateUserAccountAddressRequest request)
    {
        var userAccount = await _userAccountRepository.GetByIdAsync(request.UserAccountld);

        var userAccountAddress = new UserAccountAddressModel
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            AddressName = request.AddressName,
            UserAccountld = request.UserAccountld,
            StreetName = request.StreetName,
            Number = request.Number,
            District = request.District,
            PostalCode = request.PostalCode,
            Principal = request.Principal,
            UserAccount = userAccount,
        };

        await _userAccountAddressRepository.AddAsync(userAccountAddress);
    }
```

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: So does this repro when you eliminate your extra layers of custom repository and just use the DbContext?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353402/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-in-entity-framework-core) also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353402/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-in-entity-framework-core and https://stackoverflow.com/a/17478953/14868997

Comment: Check that your repository classes are having the same DbContext instance injected into them, I.e. a Context with a lifetime scope set to the Request and that they aren't doing something like a `using(var context = new AppDbContext())` within each method, or newing up a DbContext in the constructor. This issue looks like the DbContext that UserAddressRepository is using isn't treating the UserAccount as a tracked entity so it is trying to insert it.